# Why am I getting this error when running Scala 2.13 tests in IntelliJ, but not with Scala 2.12?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, scala-2.13

I am getting the following error when I try to run tests in IntelliJ (2019.1), Scala IntelliJ plugin v2019.1.8, with Scala 2.13:

```
Exception in thread "ScalaTest-dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(Lscala/collection/Seq;)Lscala/collection/convert/Decorators$AsJava;
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.treeBuilder.ParallelTreeBuilder.getOrdinalList(ParallelTreeBuilder.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.treeBuilder.ParallelTreeBuilder$SuiteTree.<init>(ParallelTreeBuilder.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.treeBuilder.ParallelTreeBuilder.initRun(ParallelTreeBuilder.java:261)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporterWithLocation.apply(ScalaTestReporterWithLocation.java:59)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.$anonfun$run$10(DispatchReporter.scala:249)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.$anonfun$run$10$adapted(DispatchReporter.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:312)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following are my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0'

    testImplementation 'org.scalatic:scalatic_2.13:3.0.8'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.0.8'
}
```

When I change the dependencies to Scala 2.12.x, the tests execute correctly in IntelliJ without error. What is going on here?

Comment: Having the same issue, switching back to 2.12 solves it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update: This has been [fixed](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/commit/76e69f2601635ac0867f2970b942cc04255c4000) in plugin version 2019.1.9.

---

It is possible IntelliJ Scala plugin needs to be updated for 2.13. Meanwhile try workaround by selecting the checkboxes `Use sbt` and  `Use UI with sbt` under test's [`Edit configuration...`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#test_scalaTest). According to [Dmitrii Naumenko](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15558#focus=streamItem-27-3540450.0-0):

> This is fixed in the
>
> - 2019.1 EAP #2019.1.8.21
> - 2019.2 Nightly
> - Will be available soon in 2019.2 EAP and 2019.1 new Release

Regarding Gradle, try configuring to delegate to [Gradle Test Runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-tests-in-gradle.html#configure_gradle_test_runner)

1. Remove exising ScalaTest runners
2. Go to `Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner`
3. Select the checkbox `Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle`
4. Choose `Gradle Test Runner`

Comment: In my case, I am using Gradle, but I did try selecting build, run, and run tests with Gradle, and it did not work.

Comment: Running tests from the command line has always worked though.

Comment: Does it not work if changing `Run tests using` to `Gradle Test Runner` described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/runner.html

Comment: The first time, I thought I was changing the setting you are referring to, but I was not. I looked again and did find the correct place to make the change. It still did not work though.

Comment: Did you select the checkbox `Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle`?

Comment: I still have this issue using maven and Intellij 2020.1.4, even when I check  Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven in maven tab